# Fill a textbox based on another textbox text

Tags: c#, textbox, uwp

I have TextBoxA and TextBoxB. What i want to do is , whenever i put a number (yes, both of the textboxes values are always integers) in TextBoxA , TextBoxB should "autocomplete" with value (100-TextBoxA). Same thing goes for TextBoxB.  The sum of TextBoxA and TextBoxB should always be 100.

Here's what i've already tried:

```
static void TextBoxA_TextChanged()...
{
  int a = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxA.Text);
  int b = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxB.Text);
  string text = (100-a).ToString();
  TextBoxB.Text = text;
}

Static void TextBoxB_TextChanged()...
{
  int a = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxA.Text);
  int b = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxB.Text);
  string text = (100-b).ToString();
  TextBoxA.Text = text;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What part isn't working? What do you mean when you say "doesn't work"? What happens instead?

Comment: what happens if you step through the code.. also since you you can't write (100-b) without wrapping that around `" "` show us what values are in each textbox, values in a text box are strings so I don't see the need to use variables declared as int.. when you are trying to pass `(100-b)` use string.Concat or string.Join or just keep the values as their original state..which are `Strings`

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't this cause some kind of loop because as soon as one textbox changed the other would change...causing the other to change...and so on and so forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can try:

```
private void TextBoxA_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    int num = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(TextBoxA.Text, out num))
    {
        string text = (100 - num).ToString();
        TextBoxB.Text = text;
    }
}

private void TextBoxB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(TextBoxB.Text, out num))
    {
        string text = (100 - num).ToString();
        TextBoxA.Text = text;
    }
}
```

This will autocomplete on either `TextBox` on `TextChanged` Event.

[image]

Comment: Even the Sum of both the `TextBox` is always 100...also make sure you mark it as solved if this has answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

First, i dont know why your event handlers are declared static.. its usually got to be :

```
private void TextBoxA_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

Secondly, you know if you have 2 textboxs, and each one triggers the other, you'll never go out of the TextChanged event.

To understand me more, here's an example :

> 1- You set TextBoxB.text = "1";
> 2- TextBoxB.TextChanged triggers, it
>   sets TextBoxA.Text = "2"; 
> 3- TextBoxA.TextChanged triggers, it sets
>   TextBoxB.Text = "1";

And it continues like this until i believe you'll get an Exception of memory.

EDIT : The opertator '-' works on numbers. You can't substract a number from a string. they have to be both numbers, so convert them first.

EDIT 2 :

Here's a code i wrote that works fine

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n;
        if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out n)) // Check if the text value is a number
        {
            if (n > 100) // Since you want a sum of 100
                return;

            int m = 100 - n; // remaining

            if (textBox2.Text != m.ToString()) // to not re-trigger the TextChanged event
                textBox2.Text = m.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n;
        if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out n)) // Check if the text value is a number
        {
            if (n > 100) // Since you want a sum of 100
                return;

            int m = 100 - n; // remaining

            if (textBox1.Text != m.ToString()) // to not re-trigger the TextChanged event
                textBox1.Text = m.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The first one was my mistake .. apologize!  I think it won't "loop" forever cause when both textboxes have the correct value i use a button to send those values to 2 textblocks. The problem i have now is that if i write something wrong by mistake and try to erase the current value using the keyboard the app closes

Comment: What is the error that is causing "the app closes?"
`Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.`?

Comment: I edited the answer and added a code i wrote, textbox1 is A and textbox2 is B, try it and tell me if its what you need ^^

Comment: Well i used Rakitic's answer below and it worked for the autocomplete part.. But the problem i have now is that sometimes i might have textboxA value be 100 and textboxB value be 25.. Sorry for confusing you before, when i said the sum will "always" be 100

Comment: If the value of textboxA is 100, then textboxB value will be 0 no ? how can it be 25 ^^

Comment: No wories.. I got it . It didn't need anything more than you wrote! Thanks !!   Really sorry for any confusion, this was my first question here :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is a more efficient and elegant way I'd choose using lambda expressions, without repeating the method:

```
    private void onChangeDoSum(object sender, EventArgs e,
                                TextBox substractNumber, TextBox sumNumber)
    {
        sumNumber.Text = (100 - Int32.Parse(substractNumber.Text)).ToString();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.TextChanged += (a, b) => onChangeDoSum(sender, e, textBox1, textBox2);
        textBox2.TextChanged += (a, b) => onChangeDoSum(sender, e, textBox2, textBox1);
    }
```

Alternatively use `Int32.TryParse` to prevent unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = (100 - Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString();
    }

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = (100 - Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text)).ToString();
    }
```

when I see that static word I think you have tried to create these method by yourself and you forgot to add

```
textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_Changed;
```

// I saw other post where you wrote that it could raise exception and fall. Of course it can. You can use if condition like

```
textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text != ""
```

before value would be changed or TryParse() method